# SQL Server Integrity Check error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, jobs, dbcc-checkdb

I’ve Implemented Ola's SQL Server Integrity Check on one of my **SQL 2012 Servers** and created a SQL Agent job to run it.

The job fails every time I run it, but when I run the code below manually it works well.

I've also created an output file for the job which shows that the integrity check does run on all of my databases.

```
execute [dbo].[DatabaseIntegrityCheck]
@Databases = 'ALL_DATABASES'
```

The output from the failed step is here, excluding all the text showing my database names:

> ```
> Date                    22/06/2020 14:11:26
> Log                     Job History (Integrity check)
>
> Step ID                1
> Server                 SQL-2012
> Job Name               Integrity check
> Step Name              DatabaseIntegrityCheck
> Duration               00:05:37
> Sql Severity           16
> Sql Message ID         50000
> Operator Emailed           
> Operator Net sent          
> Operator Paged 
> Retries Attempted      0
>
> The step failed.
> ```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Do you have more details on the error? Do you have anything in SQL error log? Did you check that SQL Agent has the right to access the file? Your question is missing details if we want to help you.

Comment: Check your agent in configuration or services - **SQL SERVER AGENT** should be started.

Comment: We need more details. As mentioned, hint for error messages. Errorlog, job step output, ouputfile from job execution, Ola's log table etc. Without error messages, all we can fay is "that it failed" - and you know that already.

Comment: Taking your points in turn:

- Nothing in the error log.

- Access to which file?

- Of course the Agent is running.

- I already posted the job step output.

- The output file shows that the integrity check does run on all databases, as stated in my question.  Four of the databases failed the integrity check but my understanding is that this should not cause the job to fail.  These show ErrorNumber 8956 in the CommandLog table.

- If I could find anything more than I have told you already I probably would have figured it out myself.

Comment: 50000 is a user defined error. So this is probably generated by Ola's code, calling THROW or RAISERROR. You stated in the op that you removed text with database names. We need the error text that came with that error number if we would have any chance to say something.

Comment: Does this help? Command: DBCC CHECKDB ([DB3]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  Outcome: Succeeded [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  Duration: 00:00:01 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  Date and time: 2020-06-30 16:04:39 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  Date and time: 2020-06-30 16:04:39 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  Database: [DB4] [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  Sta...  The step failed.

Comment: Thanks Collin.  The job was failing because a couple of the databases on the server did have some corruption.  After I fixed that the job ran fine.  I had expected the job to run successfully even if it found any corruption but I was wrong obviously.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that SQL Server Agent will report failure for job with step encountering error with severity other than 0, 1, or 10 (see demo below).  I don't have a 2012 instance handy - tested with SQL Server 2016. In your case there was a corruption error (8956) with severity 16. The job execution showing failed should be expected. I suspect based on quick search results (like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa2c11b2-82b1-4600-86ba-2b9ffeb7afa8/index-corruption-in-the-database)) that error 8956 will be preceded by error 8952.  **I recommend diagnosing/resolving cause of corruption**.

***Additional details:***

In your comment you mentioned that the error 8956 was logged. This is a severity 16 error:

[image: screenshot of sys.messages query message_id = 8956]

Regarding my earlier comment about SQL Server Agent job failure - here's the relevant bit from CommandExecute which is called by DatabaseIntegrityCheck:

```
DECLARE @sp_executesql nvarchar(max) = QUOTENAME(@DatabaseContext) + '.sys.sp_executesql'

.
.
.

IF @Mode = 1 AND @Execute = 'Y'
BEGIN
   EXECUTE @sp_executesql @stmt = @Command
   SET @Error = @@ERROR
   SET @ReturnCode = @Error
END

.
.
.
```

***Demo:***

So to demonstrate that job will be reported failed if step encounters sev 16 error, could create a stored proc like below which triggers sev 16 error and call from Agent job -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_TestDupObject
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
          @Error INT = 0
        , @sp_executesql nvarchar(max) = QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + '.sys.sp_executesql'
        , @SQL NVARCHAR(512) =
    'CREATE TABLE #Table(Column1 INT)

    --Will fail with Msg 2714, Level 16 (There is already an object named ''#table'' in the database)
    CREATE TABLE #Table(Column1 INT)'

    EXECUTE @sp_executesql @stmt = @SQL
    SET @Error = @@ERROR

    RETURN @Error
END
```

A more comprehensive demo iterating over severities 0-18 using RAISERROR below. First, a screenshot of results which show job success for severities 0, 1, and 10; failure for all others:
[image]

```
--Create the job using default options
USE [msdb]
GO
DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
    , @CurrentUser SYSNAME = SUSER_SNAME()
EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'TestAgentSevTolerance', 
        @enabled=1,
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name= @CurrentUser, @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_name=N'TestAgentSevTolerance', @server_name = @@SERVERNAME
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_name=N'TestAgentSevTolerance', @step_name=N'Raiserror', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'DECLARE 
      @ErrorString NVARCHAR(50)
    , @CurrentSev TINYINT
    , @CurrentTestRun TINYINT

SELECT 
      @CurrentTestRun = MAX(TestRun)
FROM AgentTest

SELECT 
    @CurrentSev = MAX(Severity)
FROM AgentTest
WHERE TestRun = @CurrentTestRun

SET @ErrorString = ''This is a test error: Severity '' + CAST(@CurrentSev AS CHAR(2)) + '' State 1''

RAISERROR(@ErrorString, @CurrentSev, 1) -- <<<<<<< This is the heart of what is being demonstrated

UPDATE AgentTest
SET JobCompleted = 1
WHERE   TestRun = @CurrentTestRun
    AND Severity =  @CurrentSev', 
        @database_name=N'SQLAgentErrorSevToleranceTest', 
        @flags=0
GO
USE [msdb]
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name=N'TestAgentSevTolerance', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @start_step_id=1
GO

USE [SQLAgentErrorSevToleranceTest]
GO
--Creating as proc so executing (in loop if desired) separately from rest of script easy
--Just iterates from MinSev to MaxSev calling job, which will in turn call RAISERROR with each sev NumberRuns times
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE usp_RunTest
(@NumberRuns TINYINT = 1
, @MinSev TINYINT = 0
, @MaxSev TINYINT = 18)--(Side note - Error sev > 18 can only be specified by sysadmin and must use WITH LOG)
AS
BEGIN
    --Sanity checking parameter values since, even though this is only for demo purposes, putting online...
    IF(@MaxSev > 18 OR @MinSev > 18)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Please specify int value from 0 to 18. Error sev > 18 can only be specified by sysadmin and must use WITH LOG', 0, 1)
        RETURN
    END
    IF(@MinSev < 0 OR @MaxSev < 0)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Negative numbers are invalid. Please specify int value from 0 to 18.', 0, 1)
        RETURN
    END
    IF(@MinSev > @MaxSev)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('The @MinSev must be <= @MaxSev. Both must be between 0 to 18 inclusive.', 0, 1)
        RETURN
    END

    DECLARE 
          @Severity TINYINT = @MinSev
        , @RetCode INT = 0
        , @BusyRetry TINYINT = 0
        , @TestRun TINYINT = 0
        , @PrintString VARCHAR(128)

    WHILE(@NumberRuns > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
              @TestRun = CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 
                    FROM [AgentTest]
                    WHERE TestRun IS NOT NULL) 
                THEN MAX(TestRun) + 1 
                ELSE 1 
              END 
        FROM [AgentTest]

        SELECT
            @Severity = CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 
                    FROM [AgentTest] 
                    WHERE   TestRun = @TestRun
                        AND Severity IS NOT NULL) 
                THEN MAX(Severity) 
                ELSE @MinSev 
              END 
        FROM [AgentTest]
        WHERE TestRun = @TestRun

        WHILE (@Severity <= @MaxSev)
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO [AgentTest](TestRun, Severity)
            VALUES(@TestRun, @Severity)

            SET @RetCode = 1
            SET @BusyRetry = 2

            WHILE (@RetCode <> 0 AND @BusyRetry > 0)
            BEGIN
                EXEC @RetCode = [msdb].[dbo].sp_start_job @job_name = N'TestAgentSevTolerance'
                SET @BusyRetry -= 1

                IF(@RetCode <> 0)
                BEGIN
                    
                    IF(@BusyRetry = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @PrintString = 'Retried job execution twice... moving on...'
                        RAISERROR(@PrintString, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
                        BREAK
                    END
                    ELSE
                        --Despite below loop, still encountered error 22022 without this wait (request to run job refused because already running)
                        SET @PrintString = 'WAITING FOR PREVIOUS JOB EXECUTION TO COMPLETE... CURRENT SEVERITY ' + CAST(@Severity AS CHAR(2))
                        RAISERROR(@PrintString, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
                        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    WHILE EXISTS(
                        SELECT 1
                        FROM [msdb].[dbo].sysjobactivity activity
                            JOIN [msdb].[dbo].sysjobs jobs
                                ON activity.job_id = jobs.job_id
                        WHERE start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
                            AND stop_execution_date IS NULL
                            AND jobs.name = N'TestAgentSevTolerance'
                        )
                    BEGIN
                        SET @PrintString = 'WAITING FOR PREVIOUS JOB EXECUTION TO COMPLETE... CURRENT SEVERITY ' + CAST(@Severity AS CHAR(2))
                        RAISERROR(@PrintString, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
                        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01.00'
                    END
                END
            END

            --Despite below loop, still encountered error 22022 without this wait (request to run job refused because already running)
            --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'

            UPDATE [AgentTest]
            SET JobFailedToStart = @RetCode
            WHERE Severity = @Severity
                AND TestRun = @TestRun

            SET @Severity += 1          
        END

        SET @NumberRuns -= 1
    END
END
GO

EXEC usp_RunTest @MinSev = 0, @MaxSev = 18, @NumberRuns = 3

SELECT 
    sql_message_id
    , sql_severity
    , CASE run_status
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'In Progress'
      END [run_status]
    , message
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory] hist
    JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] job ON job.job_id = hist.job_id
WHERE job.name = N'TestAgentSevTolerance'
    AND step_name = N'Raiserror'
    --Uncomment below two lines to make more obvious the successful job executions
    --AND run_status = 1
    --AND sql_severity NOT IN (0,10)
ORDER BY run_time DESC

--Uncomment and execute below to clean up

    --EXEC [msdb].[dbo].sp_delete_job @job_name = N'TestAgentSevTolerance'

    --USE [master]
    --GO

    --DROP DATABASE [SQLAgentErrorSevToleranceTest]
```